# Searching for correlation between emotions on the couples or partners by thermal photo

Tags: freud

I am researching about the [somatization](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Somatization) feeling with long distance contact via social media between girls and boys or dating.

So, I am trying to find some meaning between the boys and girl who date which be in contact with each others by voice or photo.

So if I have some thermographic photo from the boy and girl for the times those meet each other, during different emotion like the [below photos](https://www.google.com/search?q=thermographic%20emotion%20&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwjEv63K0Y71AhXBkKQKHQ12DWMQ2-cCegQIABAC&oq=thermographic%20emotion%20&gs_lcp=ChJtb2JpbGUtZ3dzLXdpei1pbWcQAzIHCCMQ7wMQJ1DAB1jAB2DACWgAcAB4AIAB-wGIAdgDkgEDMi0ymAEAoAEBwAEB&sclient=mobile-gws-wiz-img&ei=zEfPYcSpC8GhkgWN7LWYBg&bih=470&biw=360&client=ms-android-om-lge&prmd=ivnx&hl=fa#imgrc=1X8cIbzZ5ueSYM):

[image: thermographic photo of a man and woman]

I guess I could find out some meaningful relation between the body's hottest point on a girl and boy during their different feelings.

If possible, I like to have some comment or answer for finding some database for these photos, or academic papers ([maybe by this tags](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=fa&as_sdt=0,5&as_vis=1&q=thermographic%20photo%20couples%20twin%20dating) etc.).

Also, if there is no photo database for these purpose until now, I would like to have some comments for finding some institute for taking thermographic photo during different emotion from the couples during their dating times.

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE. Please take our [tour]. This is definitely the site for your question, and don't worry. Wherever you ask a question, you will be guided on where to ask it if it is off-topic there and the moderators can move it there for you if it is easier.